# Upgrade from 14.04 to 18.04 via 16.04 - running into issues

Tags: 16.04, usb, 18.04, asus, bios

Ok here's what we've got:

Machine: Asus N550jv-db72t
         Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
         OS type 64-bit
         Intel Core i7-4700HQ CPU @ 2.40GHz x8
         Intel Hasell Mobile
         976.0 GB

Attempting to upgrade to 18.04 but as I understand it, need to do so by installing 16.04 first.

Downloaded 16.04 to flash drive.  Log into BIOS.  There is no option to boot from USB drive.  (DVD drive presently inoperable)

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to get into something like "Boot Options". On my system, I have to tap the F12 key a few times immediately after turning on the machine (with the USB inserted). Also, just downloading the iso to a flash drive isn't enough: you need to create a Live USB. I like [mkusb](https://launchpad.net/~mkusb/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) for this job. In any case, I suggest you first try out the Live USB and then do a clean install of 18.04 (after backing up your personal data).

Answer (score 0):

If you have an internet connection available, it's probably easier to let Ubuntu handle the updating.

Run `update-manager`, it should prompt you to update to 16.04. If not, check your update settings:

1. On the Update manager, click on *Settings...*
2. Select the *Updates* tab
3. Open the *Notify me of a new Ubuntu version* dropdown and select *For long-term support versions*
4. Click *Close* and run `update-manager` again.

Then, follow the prompts to update to 16.04. Once you're on 16.04, you can repeat the process with one minor alteration: Since LTS-to-LTS updates are only recommended once the first point release (18.04.1, in this case) has been released, you will have to use `update-manager -d` to start the update process.